# Labels on sonar dashboard not shown correctly

Tags: sonarqube

I am using sonarcube 3.7.3 and the labels on sonar dashboard are not coming correctly. I am not able to attach the image due to access issues. One example is the label beside the login input box. Normally it read **Login** but currently it is reading **layout.login**.  This has started coming only recently and am not aware of any changes done on the sonar server.
The differential view dropdown is also showing only one value though I have set-up 3 differential views.
Can you please let me kmow what might be causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. The sonar administrator restarted the sonar server and after that I no longer see the issue.
I am still not sure what was causing the issue. Anybody who faces this can do a serevr restart to see if it solves their problem.

Comment: I suggest you use the 4.2 version which has a lot of improvements.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and in my case it seems it was because I was using my own user for the sonar-maven-plugin, which was setting "en_US" as the locale, while SonarQube uses "en-US" instead.

I solved this by using a special SonarQube user for the plugin.